# Simple Html Dom Parser: how to recursively parse using data arrays from db?

Tags: php, foreach, simple-html-dom

So, the thing is that I've got Simple Html Dom Parser, and trying to do the following:

- there is a database with only one table ('urls'), which contain list of target site's urls and links which should be on the page relevant to given url. Example: 
  url: site.com/somepage.html    link: partnersite.com/page.html
  And couple more thousands of such pairs.

To check one pair, I can use such code:

```
$url = 'http://example.com/product'; 
$html = file_get_html($url);
$links = array();
foreach($html->find('a[href^="http://patnersite.com/product-category/bags/"]') as $a) {
 $links[] = $a->href;
}

if ($links) { 
echo $url . $link_ok .'<br>';
}
else 
{
echo $url . $link_bad;
}
}
```

And I'll get a result. BUT. How to do this in a loop for all the entries from the database?

The following code gives only lots of php-warnings, mistakes and notices:

```
 $result= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  `urls`");
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  }
foreach($result as $entry) {
$htmli = file_get_html($row['addr']);
$linkss = array();
$htmli->find('a[href^="$row["link"]"]') as $a) 
 $linkss[] = $a->href;
}

if ($linkss) { 

echo $url . $link_ok .'<br>';
}
else 
{
echo $url . $link_bad;
}
```

The main question is still the same - what's wrong with te code above? How to loop parsing of arrays of data from database?

Comment: Have you tried fixing all those php warnings, mistakes and notices you mention?

Comment: What warning and notices?

Comment: @malarzm, yes I tried.. But as a result - here I am, asking my question on stackoverflow xD

Comment: @Perdeep Singh
The most often mistake is "Invalid argument supplied for foreach"

Comment: In that case you need null check. so wrap your foreach inside if($result).

Saying that, still I would like to say that there are lot of bad practices happening and even you fix current issue you will have maintainability/scalability issue with this part of code.

Comment: @Perdeep Singh, yes, bad practices happened. Question persists: how to loop that parsing behaviour?(

Comment: Sorry but not clear on what's the issue, where you having trouble? What's the empty while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  } is for?  or is it pseudo code?